# Twilio Play verb read URL rather than playing audio file

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio

Using the Twilio SDK for .NET Core, my web app return

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Response>
   <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
 </Response>
```

It's straight from Twilio's API. For some reason, when I call on phone, it use text to speech to read the URL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here

Would you mind sharing your code? Using the below sample in ASP.NET Core, you can get the cowbell to play when Twilio phone number is called.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    response.Play("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3", loop: 10);
    return Content(response.ToString(), "application/xml");
}
```

This presumes that the number is configured to do a GET request to your API method. Hopefully this code sample helps.